# main.cpp|| undefined reference to `MyClass::loadDatas(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'|

Tags: c++, string

I encounter a problem using `std::string` in parameters :

`MyClass` has a method like this

```
public:  
    void loadDatas(string filename);
```

In my `main.cpp` I have the following simple code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "myclass.hpp";

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string foo = "test.txt";
    cout << foo << endl; // Print Hello Kitty, no problems

    MyClass i;
    // The following line raise :
    // obj/Release/src/main.o||In function `main':|
    // main.cpp|| undefined reference to `MyClass::loadDatas(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'|
    // ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
    i.loadDatas(foo);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

So it looks like `libstdc++` is well linked (because I'm able to print the text using `cout`), but passing a `string` in parameters raise an error and I don't understand why.

Could someone help me please ?

EDIT : I made a mistake, in fact it is `i.loadDatas(foo);` (I corrected it). My source code isn't in english so I tryed to made a simple version for you in english. I really call an instance method and not a static method.

EDIT 2 : Complete source code

**personnage.hpp**

```
#ifndef PERSONNAGE_H
#define PERSONNAGE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/xpath.h>
#include <libxml/xpathInternals.h>

#include "carte.hpp"

using namespace std;

class Personnage : public Carte
{

    public:

        Personnage();

        void chargerPersonnage(string nom);

        virtual ~Personnage();

    private:

        //! Le texte d'accroche de la carte
        string _accroche;

};

#endif // PERSONNAGE_H
```

**personnage.cpp**

```
#include "personnage.hpp"

Personnage::Personnage() : Carte("Sans titre")
{

}

void chargerPersonnage(string nom)
{

}

Personnage::~Personnage()
{
    //dtor
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "personnage.hpp"

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string test = "Hello Kitty";
    cout << test << endl;

    Personnage test2;
    test2.chargerPersonnage(test);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**error log**

```
obj/Release/src/main.o||In function `main':|
main.cpp|| undefined reference to `Personnage::chargerPersonnage(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Without seeing `myclass.hpp` and `myclass.cpp`, it's difficult to say.  Also, we'd need to see how you're invoking the compiler/linker.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth : The function in myclass.cpp is empty (to avoid other possible errors), and myclass.hpp only declare The constructor, the destructor and this methode. Libraries included are : iostream and string (there is libxml/tree.h, but it is not used in the source code). And the compiler is invoked by Code::Blocks (it use g++ and link with -lxml2 only (I tryed using -llibstdc but I doesn't change anything)).

Comment: Please add the code for both of these files to your question.  It's very difficult to come to any conclusion without seeing the *exact* code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I added the complete source code (it's only missing one class (Carte) but it don't do anything for the moment I could remove the inheritance if necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined `class Personnage` as having a **member function** `chargerPersonnage`, but in personnage.cpp you define a **free function** `chargerPersonnage` instead.

You appear to know the correct syntax, as you did `Personnage`'s constructor and destructor correctly, but just to make it clear: Change `void chargerPersonnage(string nom) { }` to `void Personnage::chargerPersonnage(string nom) { }` in personnage.cpp.

Comment: Thank you very much ! 5 years without programming in C++ has had a bad effect on me... I'm feeling so stupid... Thank you again ildjarn.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyClass i;
MyClass.loadDatas(foo); 
     //^this syntax is wrong. Dot is used with "instance" of class!
```

Wrong syntax. I think you wanted to write:

```
i.loadDatas(foo);
```

However, if `loadData` is a `static` member function, then you've to write it:

```
MyClass::loadDatas(foo);
     //^^ note the difference!
```

---

REPLY TO YOUR EDIT:

I don't think it's possible to point out the error in your code without seeing more code. Maybe, you've not defined the function `loadDatas`. Make sure you've defined it. Also, check out the spelling, syntax and all.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: if you do not use `use namespace std;` in your header file (which you shouldn't because it can be evil), you need to define your method with `std::string filename`.

Comment: +1; **not** the solution to this problem, but excellent advice in general.

Comment: Just a note: I posted my answer before the OP added his complete source.

Comment: Oh, I know, I saw the timestamps. I just wanted to call extra attention to your answer even though it wouldn't be the accepted answer. :-]

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems in your code:

- `loadDatas` lacks a return type
- I think you mean  `i.loadDatas(foo);` and not  `MyClass.loadDatas(foo);`

Comment: Yes that's write and return type is void (see EDIT note).